# В списке intellisense нет нужного метода

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Есть работающий класс, использующий `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    namespace excel_1
    {
        class ClassExcel1
        {
            private Excel.Application excelapp;
            private Excel.Window excelWindow;
            private Excel.Sheets excelsheets;
            private Excel.Worksheet excelworksheet;
            private Excel.Range excelcells;
            private Excel.Workbooks excelappworkbooks;
            private Excel.Workbook excelappworkbook;

            public void Read () {
                excelapp = new Excel.Application();
                excelapp.Visible = true;
                excelappworkbooks = excelapp.Workbooks;
                excelappworkbook = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(@"d:\ProgramFilesD\Microsoft Visual Studio\my projects\testApp1\Open.xls");
                excelsheets = excelappworkbook.Worksheets;

                // речь про эту строку:
                excelworksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelsheets.get_Item(1); 

                excelcells = excelworksheet.get_Range("A2", Type.Missing);
                string sStr = Convert.ToString(excelcells.Value2);
                Console.WriteLine(sStr);
            }
        }
    }
```

При наборе кода в строке:

```
excelworksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelsheets.get_Item(1);
```

когда ставлю последнюю точку, в списке `intellisense` нет метода `get_Item()`, а другие члены класса есть в списке. Имя вызываемого метода приходится писать руками. Тем не менее код работает.

Почему метода нет в списке?

Comment: [тыц](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.get_item.aspx) - _This API supports the Visual Studio infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. Вместо этого метода можно использовать свойство Item._

Comment: Также смотрите [Excel Interop difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31360204/5045688).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Промахнулись мимо поля ответ. ;)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.